# Post "featured image" is not saving when I choose from existing media

Tags: wordpress

When I select multiple featured Image in a post, it shows on the edit post page, but when I save draft, the page refresh and it doesn't save all the selected images. Sometimes it overwrite another image. I tried disabling plugins but the problem doesn't resolved, it happens most of the times but not all the times. Any Idea?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you disable your theme and all plugins, reverting to Twenty17 - does the issue persist? Have you check for any console log errors within the Chrome web dev tools? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @David: Yes I checked for the log errors, but it doesn't show any. I disabled all the plugins and checked too. The weird thing is it just happens sometimes.

Comment: are you viewing an older previewed page link, loading an older revision via the URL?

Comment: No, I am clicking directly from a post. Trying different post every time.

Comment: I know, it updates the featured images from this line -  update_post_meta($postId, "extra_feature_images", $l);, it seems like it doesn't get all "idsSelected" sometimes.

Comment: what plugin is this? This is not default core WP functionality from what you describe. Have you reported this to the plugins devs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in save_postdata($post_id)function (this is a click event of save post button).

```html
 if( isset($_POST["action"])  ){
            $contains = "feature_image";
            foreach ($_POST as $post => $key) {
                if (strpos($post, $contains) !== FALSE) {
                    $selected_images .= $key."-";
                }
            }
            update_post_meta($post_id, "extra_feature_images", trim($selected_images, "-"));
```

Answer (score -1):

It happens with js issue also sometimes once confirm with developer tool -> console log.

thank you.